# Removing last character from a line using regex

Tags: regex

I just started learning regex and I'm trying to understand how it possible to do the following:

If I have:

```
helmut_rankl:20Suzuki12
helmut1195:wasserfall1974
helmut1951:roller11
```

Get:

```
helmut_rankl:20Suzuki1
helmut1195:wasserfall197
helmut1951:roller1
```

I tried using `.$` which actually match the last character of a string, but it doesn't match letters and numbers.

How do I get these results from the input?

Comment: Could you explain what "doesn't match letters and numbers mean"? `.` should match anything except line terminators. If your goal is to match only numbers, try `[0-9]$`.

Comment: Well, if I try the regex command .$ on the example above, it only give result on the last string and remove the 1, but the first two strings aren't affected by it, I still don't know how that possible

Comment: I don't know in what context you're trying this (in Python, on a website?), but if you can, try setting `gm` as the flag, the `m` stands for multiline which enables you to use `^` and `$` on every line.

Comment: Regex doesn't affect the string; regex can't "remove" characters. For that, you need app code or a tools like notepad++. Please add the tag of the language/tool you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the whole line, and assert a single char to the right if you want to match at least a single character.

```
.+(?=.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/buYPa4/1)

If you also want to match empty strings:

```
.*(?=.)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want with regex's match function.

`^(.*).$`

Broken down:

`^` matches the start of the string

`(` and `)` denote a capturing group. The matches which fall within it are returned.

`.*` matches everything, as much as it can.

The final `.` matches any single character (i.e. the last character of the line)

`$` matches the end of the line/input

Comment: It works [see here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/FMD)